# Make Div autosize depending on elements - two columns one aligned to bottom

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

So consider I have these two situations:

- http://jsfiddle.net/CtYYJ/ <---------- first scenario

Here Is the general situation in which the text in the left div is longer than the input elements on the right div.

How can I specify the size of the wrapper to be the same as the right div elements length and in the same scenario the right div input elements be aligned at the bottom of the wrapper like in my first jsfiddle example?

What I'm also struggling out is another scenario when there would be only one of the four texts in the right div and on the left div only the button.

How can I re-size the wrapper to one line and display the elements inline using the same CSS style as for the first scenario ?

- http://jsfiddle.net/zfGeW/ <---------- second scenario

Please give me some pointers out with this cause I am getting mad on random attempting with

- `height: auto;`
- `min-height: 50px;`

and other CSS properties I've found online.

Still I've noticed that there is no way to have the right `div` input elements aligned to bottom without specifying a fixed size for the wrapper, isn't there any workaround for this and avoid the `table` tag ?

Here is an online doodle of the two scenarios I am talking about: [example](http://dosketch.com/view.php?k=oDhrX2xYTOEryH1hm1rf)

Please keep in mind that the content of the right and left div elements is variable, the two examples i fiddled are the extreme cases:

1. left div  content longer that the right div with right div content aligned to bottom.
2. Left and right div have the same content size and therefore wrapper displays the content on one line (left div text and right div the button).

Comment: Lucian, your scenarios are a bit confusing. Maybe attaching a graphic representation of your query will help people answer your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking your graphics I think there is no CSS way for what you ask.
Would using the faux columns method and positioning your right content fixed or absolutely in the bottom corner be a solution?

http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns

```
<div style="width:400px;position:relative;">
    <div style="height: 200px; width:250px;">left</div>
    <div style="height: 50px; width:150px;position: absolute;right: 0; bottom: 0;">right</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/26V6E/

Comment: Yes, that could be a solver for my situation. the only thing I had to adjust is the "height: 100%;" or "height: auto;" for the left div (since it should have the same size as the content I put inside)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried: height: 100% ?

Comment: of course, and the right div content gets mis-alligned (try it on my jsfiddle example and see :) )